Bicep modules files are not getting updated in container registry
I have created the container registry in order to upload the bicep modules and the use those in multiple places. I have uploaded the files and it's working fine but now I needed to change the bicep files in the default version and I am trying to do that using following command, I can see the increment in Manifest count on the azure portal > Container Registry > Repositories > MyFile

az bicep publish -f "myfile.bicep" --target "br:myregistry.azurecr.io/folder/myfile:default" --force

I am even using --force tag to update the content but it's not working.

looking at the documentation it should be --target "br:myregistry.azurecr.io/folder/myfile:default --force"

the --force parameter should be inside the quotes

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/bicep?view=azure-cli-latest#az-bicep-publish

The tag "default --force" is not valid. Valid characters are alphanumeric, ".", "", or "-" but the tag cannot begin with ".", "", or "-".

As Thomas rightly pointed out, the --force parameter should not be placed within quotes in the command. According to the documentation, the correct syntax should keep --force as a standalone parameter.
For example, if you have a bicep file named myfile.bicep
resource  storageAccount  'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-09-01' = {
  name: 'mystorage${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}'  
  location: resourceGroup().location  
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
}

output  storageAccountName  string = storageAccount.name


which you have uploaded to your acr

and now you want to update the bicep module and republish. For example, update the SKU
resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-09-01' = {
  name: 'st${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}'  // Shortened prefix to "st"
  location: resourceGroup().location
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_GRS'  // Updated SKU
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
}

output storageAccountName string = storageAccount.name


Run the az bicep publish command again with the --force option to overwrite the previous version
az bicep publish -f "./myfile.bicep" --target "br:arkoacr.azurecr.io/folder/myfile:default" --force

without force

with --force

Now check in your acr-
earlier

now

Reference-
az bicep | Microsoft Learn

@Imran Ahmad Shahid hope it resolved your query

It didnt, I tried to publish the bicep using az bicep publish -f "myfile.bicep" --target "br:myregistry.azurecr.io/folder/myfile:default" --force, it didn\t work

what error are you getting?

I didnt get any error but file is not updating and when I am trying to use the bicep, it is still the old version

Are you following the exact steps? It got updated for me as you can see in the screenshot. You are saying you are pushing the updated image into the acr and its getting pushed but updates not showing or new image is not getting pushed?
